# Django: Rendering AWS S3 static files through css background-image

Tags: html, css, django, amazon-s3

I was having some difficulties rendering my static data through the css background-image tag.

For example, take the following piece of code:

```
<section class="banner-area" style="background-image: url('../../static/main/img/search4.jpg')>;
```

When I inspect the element on my browser, I can see that it is not being linked to AWS S3 bucket, and the  url remains exactly the same as per the following:

```
url('../../static/main/img/search4.jpg')
```

However if I render an image using the source tag, I get the behaviour I want, for example:

```
<img src="{% static 'main/img/search4.jpg' %}/>
```

Here, when inspecting the element, I can see in the browser that it is being linked to my S3 Bucket as per the following:

```
src="https://mybucket-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/main/img/search4.jpg?ETC...."
```

In my **settings.py**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "main/static"),
    
                        )
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/img')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATIC_URL='https://mybucket-bucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/'
```

Can you please advise ?

Kind regards,
Marvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
url('../../static/main/img/search4.jpg')
```

to

```
url('{% static 'main/img/search4.jpg' %}')
```

The reason for this is your site is hosted on a domain different from your s3 bucket domain so the browser is unable to resolve the relative url

For example, if your website is at `example.com` the browser attempts to pop off the last 2 path components(parts of the url following a forward slash e.g /component1/component2/) so it just does nothing. You can place the relative path in your css file since it's hosted on the same domain as your image